# Class definition parameter vs. Normal class definition

Tags: python, class

What is the difference between the two? Don't both of these have the same functionality? I don't understand the whole point of the `object` parameter.

```
class Car(object): # object parameter
    def foobar():
        print("Hello World!\n")
```

vs.

```
class Car(): # No parameter
    def foobar():
        print("Hello World!\n")
```

Comment: The first is a new style class, and the latter is an old style class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, the former is a "new-style class" and the latter is an "old-style class" that only exists for backwards compatibility.  You should never use the latter for anything new.

In Python 3, I believe there is no difference at all.  You can even leave out the parentheses entirely.

Comment: So is there a technically right way to do it?

Comment: @user1757703 As you probably want new-style classes, always use `(object)` if you want to stay backward-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

In two words:

```
# new style
class Car(object):
    pass
```

> A "New Class" is the recommended way to create a class in modern
>   Python.

```
# classic style
class Car():
    pass
```

> A "Classic Class" or "old-style class" is a class as it existed in
>   Python 2.1 and before. They have been retained for backwards
>   compatibility. This page attempts to list the differences.

Please look at:

- http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/new-style-classes.html
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass
- https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/